# "Install-PackageProvider ContainerImage -Force" throws error in Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I ran the command "***Install-PackageProvider ContainerImage -Force***" in the PowerShell in Administrative mode as a part of the process to install container in Windows Server 2016.

***I encountered the following error***:

WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'ContainerImage'. The
package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At line:1 char:1

- Install-PackageProvider ContainerImage -Force
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-Pac
  kageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackagePro
  vider
  ```

Also attached is the image [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqjpg.png)

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because you should add default repository first, try adding it with following command in power shell:

```
Register-PSRepository -Default
```

It should work now!

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as I understand it, is that PowerShell by default uses TLS 1.0 for web requests, which will not work in our case. So this needs to be changed. Thankfully, this is an easy change. Just add the following line to your scripts:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

This will force the use of TLS 1.2 (you can also make it use 1.1 if you want for some reason).

Note though that this will only change it for that PowerShell session, so it will need to be executed for each script you run.